# Is there a way of adding a list into another list in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have created a list in javascript :-

`var childlist = {};
 chilslist.id="someId";
 childlist.values = [];`

I want to insert this list into another list say var parentlist = {};

I have multiple copies of childList, which i need to place into parentlist and pass it on.
Is there a way to achieve this in javascript please help.

Comment: Wait, `childlist` is not a list. It's just an Object containing an Array. (By looking at your code it looks like you are mimicking Objects in Java...lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parentList = {
    id: "someparentid",
    lists: []
};

parentList.lists.push(childList1);
parentList.lists.push(childList2);
...
```

You could also make the parentList an array instead of an object (if you need only the lists and no IDs or whatever) like this `var parentList = [];` and then do just `parentList.push(childList);`.

Comment: Both ways will work fine, you needs to choose which one you need.

Comment: @user3289248 What are you having problems with? It's pretty straghtforward from here.

Comment: I am getting the following marshling error.. org.directwebremoting.extend.MarshallException: Error marshalling java.util.List: .. There is an ajax call to which I need to feed this list , placing it into another object.. The object looks like this.. public class xyz {List<abc> parentList;}, the parentlist constructed here has to go into this list.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait... You tagged your question `JavaScript`, not `Java` and so I gave you answers for JavaScript... The difference between them is enormous! Please confirm this.

Comment: Yes I need to construct this list in javascript and pass it onto ajax call.. I am very new to javascript.. here is my complete problem..

Comment: public class xyz {List<abc> parentList;}
public class abc {
String id;
List<cba> cba;
}.. I have the data in javascript... I want to reconstruct in the way of above format and send it to ajax call
@ajax
public class saveSettings(xyz xyz){
List<abc> parentList = xyz.getabc();
}

Comment: I see, but where does Java come in? This changes things a bit. The JS part I gave you is fine, but for the ajax communication it might be the easiest in this case to use JSON. In JS, use `JSON.stringify(parentList);` to get the JSON string you will send with ajax, and then parse it in Java (there are many libraries for this). If you don't manage to do it, I suggest opening another question for additional problems, because I gave you the answer to this one.

Comment: here is my complete problem
public class SomeClass{
List<Template> templateSettings;

}

public class Template{

String id;
List<TemplateChild> child;
}

public class TemplateChild{
String id;
String something;
}



at the ajax level i have
@ajax
public class saveSettings(SomeClass someclass){
List<Template> templateSettings = someclass.getTemplateSettings();
}

So, in which format or structure should i pass the data from js..

Comment: Please, open another question for it, because Stack Overflow is not a forum but a knowledge base, and you shouldn't change the original questions you post (and it's really hard to read code in comments) so that the answers will remain correct for the original questions and it would be easier for people to find what they're looking for. See the help pages: http://stackoverflow.com/tour And to answer that last question, I still think JSON would be the best format to use here.

Comment: yes JSON is the answer for it..I have opened a new question , hope you could help me out there in the new thread..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755177/need-help-in-constructing-the-json-for-the-following

Comment: Nice, I see you already got some nice answers there (you probably need to be a bit more descriptive when writing questions, btw). Let's close this one then if you're happy with the JS part. When you select an answer that helped you the most, the question will be marked as closed/answered.