# Need help in constructing the JSON for the following

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a problem at hand..

```
public class SomeClass{
List<Template> templateSettings; 
}

public class Template{

String id;
List<TemplateChild> child;
}

public class TemplateChild{
String id;
String something;
}
  at the ajax level i have
@ajax
public class saveSettings(SomeClass someclass){
List<Template> templateSettings = someclass.getTemplateSettings();
}
```

Its a bit complex , can someone help me in constructing the JSON for this, i am very new to javascript.. thanks..

Comment: As Template is a list in above, i can have multiples of templateSettings..thanks

Comment: Are you trying to generate json from the above code? You have tagged it as Java, is this correct (looks kinda like it could be C#)?
Its a bit unclear what you are trying to do and what your issue is, please try to describe it a bit better if you could.

Comment: Uh, well, APIs for JSON {de,}serialization exist for Java and work pretty much out of the box. Jackson is such an API for instance, and so is Gson. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: No, above VO are indicators as to how the structure of JSON should look for the saveSettings ajax call to accept.. I have the data but i dont know how to construct proper JSON for Template class in above.. can you guys please help..

Answer (score 0):

`Gson` `library` will do that for you, Its pretty simple to use, here is the [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

You can simply download the `jar` file and create the `object` like this

{ Gson gson = new Gson();
    String convertedJson = gson.toJson(yourobject);}

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should look like

```
templetSettings= [{
    template = {id="someId", childs=[{id="someId", something="something"},{id="someId2", something="something2"}]}},{
    template = {//same as above},{
    template = {//same as above}
]
```

Use JSONObject and JSONArray to create this kind of structure. Its pretty easy to use really

```
JSONArray templateSettings = new JSONArray();

for(//configure loop accordigly) { 
    JSONObject template = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray childs = new JSONArray();
    for (//Configure accordingly) {
        JSONObject child = new JSONObject;

        child.put("id", "someId");
        child.put("something", "something");

        childs.add(child);
    }

    template.put("id", "someId");
    template.put("childs", childs);

    templateSettings.add(template);

}
```

After this you only need to do is

```
out.write(templateSettings.toString());
```

And you are done

To do this on javaScript side loop accordingly and take help from this example

http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/636vN/

Comment: Can I get more details about JSONObject please

Comment: Here is how you should use JSONObject and JSONArray.

Comment: I believe this is at the Java level, how do I do it at the JS level, hoppe so I am not asking a wrong question here

Comment: You want to construct a JSON at client side and then send that to server?

Comment: Haven't we covered the JS part in your other question? After you create/modify your JS object, you can then use JSON.stringify on it to convert it into a string that you can easily send via ajax.